# r - learning RSelenium, a few basic beginner technical issues

Tags: r, web-scraping

I've looked at https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/94 and https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/82 but was not able to solve my problem. It didn't help that this person was on Windows, and I am on Mac (El Capitan, version 10.11.6)

I am trying to learn data scraping with RSelenium, but some of the technical aspects of it are giving me issues early on. I have a few questions first and then will share my code:

(1) Right away, it says that startServer() is deprecated. specifically, that:

```
startServer()

# output
Warning message:
startServer is deprecated.
Users in future can find the function in 
file.path(find.package("RSelenium"), "example/serverUtils").
The sourcing/starting of a Selenium Server is a users responsiblity. 
Options include manually starting a server see 
vignette("RSelenium-basics", package = "RSelenium")
and running a docker container see  
vignette("RSelenium-docker", package = "RSelenium")
```

. 
what should i use in place of startSever(), or what do I need to change on my computer? I'm confused as to what this warming message is saying.

(2) Since it's just a warning, I continue by trying to open a browser in chrome. I quickly run into another error:

```
remDr = remoteDriver$new(browserName = 'chrome')
remDr$open()

# output 
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
$webdriver.remote.sessionid
[1] "4d0ad1d9-1c4b-4171-8dce-ba8363f5849e"

$locationContextEnabled
[1] TRUE

$webStorageEnabled
[1] TRUE

$takesScreenshot
[1] TRUE

$javascriptEnabled
[1] TRUE

$message
[1] "session not created exception\nfrom unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {\"auxData\":{\"frameId\":\"34144.1\",\"isDefault\":true},\"id\":1,\"name\":\"\",\"origin\":\"://\"}\n  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64)"

$hasTouchScreen
[1] TRUE

$platform
[1] "ANY"

$cssSelectorsEnabled
[1] TRUE

$id
[1] "4d0ad1d9-1c4b-4171-8dce-ba8363f5849e"
```

the $message line output mentions that the session was not created. on my desktop, what i see is that chrome opens initially for a split second, and then closes / crashes / doesn't actually open up. I try again for firefox, and get:

```
remDr = remoteDriver$new(browserName = 'firefox')
remDr$open()

# output 
[1] "Connecting to remote server"

Selenium message:The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: java.lang.IllegalStateException
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

it is frustrating to try to learn this, but to not even be able to get past the very first steps of opening a browser. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: grabbing lunch but will be back in 30 minutes to answer Qs / respond to comments

Comment: Your second error indicates that you have an old chromedriver 2.20 (the most recent is 2,25) trying to run the most recent version of chrome. Updating your chromedriver will most likely sort this issue out.

Comment: The error message for firefox indicates that geckodriver is now needed for driving firefox. On MAC this can be installed via brew as outlined below.

Comment: To avoid all the above it is easiest to run a Docker container that has the appropriate browser/selenium server/geckodriver/chromedriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted `checkForServer` and `startServer` are deprecated you may be able to use them as follows:

```
unlink(file.path(find.package("RSelenium"), "bin"), recursive = TRUE, force = TRUE)
RSelenium::checkForServer()
```

For Firefox:

In terminal, run the following command

```
brew install geckodriver
```

Running selenium at the default port on Mac has an issue as often Kerberos is already running on default port 4444 on MAC. Run the following command in R console

```
selServ <- RSelenium::startServer(args = c("-port 5556"))
remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(extraCapabilities = list(marionette = TRUE), port=5556)
remDr$open()
......
# when finished
selServ$stop()
```

For chrome:

```
brew install chromedriver
```

Running selenium at the default port on Mac has an issue. Run the following command in R console

```
selServ <- RSelenium::startServer(args = c("-port 5556"))
remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome", 
                                 extraCapabilities = list(marionette = TRUE),
                                 port=5556)
remDr$open()
......
# when finished
selServ$stop()
```

If the above doesnt help then look at running a Docker container see
http://rpubs.com/johndharrison/RSelenium-Docker and https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium . This basically involves running a Docker container using something like:

```
$ docker run -d -p 5556:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome:3.0.1-aluminum
```

then a selenium server and chrome browser should be accessible on port 5556 which you can connect to giving appropriate arguments in `remoteDriver`.

Comment: thanks a ton, give me a bit of time to sift through all of this but i appreciate the detailed response

Comment: chromedriver appears to have been the issue with chrome, which is my preference. thanks again. will hold off on a docker container unless i run into other issues probably

Comment: Thats good to hear. If the CheckForServer/StartServer work for you then you can keep using them They have been deprecated and moved to example folder as users were having issues with them cross-platform. There is not to my knowledge ATM any resilient way to manage a process via R cross-platform.